# Is it a correct approach to pass useState setter to a child for updating parents state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

We can pass a callback to a child as props and update the state but I was just wondering can I pass useState setter to the child and call it directly in child to update parents state?

Something like:

```js
function Parent(){
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  
  return(
    <Child setData={setData}/>
  );
}

function Child({setData}){
  useEffect(()=>{
    setData('new data'); //Calling setter here to update
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not ?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that. If the child component is nested multiple layers deep, you can also use useContext() hook to update the main component's state easily.

Comment: It isn't bad practice to pass state setter as props of Child Component. But in your case this can lead into a infinite loop as when the child call `setData` It will trigger the rerender of the `Parent` which by the way will rerender the `Child` Component which will another time trigger the rerender of the parent and so on and so fourth.

Comment: yes, in this case, it will go into infinite rendering. This was just an example to show what I wanted to achieve. But thanks for answering.
Also, is the usState setter created every time on rerender? Would parent rerender trigger child rerender because setData function is not the same as the previous one?

Comment: Separation of concerns means your child component shouldn't "know" about your parent component. In that vein your child component would call it something more useful to itself, like `onDataChange`. That said it's better to wrap your state updater functions in an instance of  `useCallback`, and pass that into your child.

Comment: I suspect that this ❓ is prompted by [this from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). With `class` components, we need to rely on receiving the `event` information from the child to perform the state update. Apparently, not a concern to allow the child to update the state directly using the `useState` **update function.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. In fact, it is good practice to do that. To avoid unnecessary re-renders and infinite loops, either include `setData` in the dependency array of the Child's `useEffect` or wrap the `data` in a `useCallback` in the Parent component. Also, it is recommended to initialise the data to some initial value when using `useState`. In your case, I would initialise it to `null` -> `const [data, setData] = useState(null)`

Example with the dependency array:

```js
function Child({ setData }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setData("new data"); //Calling setter here to update
  }, [setData]);

  return (...);
}
```

If you want to pass it to a child that is multiple levels deep, I would suggest using Context. With context, you can then use the `useState` in any child and you don't need to pass it as props throughout all of the children between the `Parent` and the `Child` that you want to use it in.

Example with the Context:

```js
// Step 1. Create context
const MyContext = React.createContext();

// Step 2. Create a custom hook that will return Context
// This will allow you to use the context in any number of children more easily.
// And it will also make sure that it is only used within Parent component
const useData = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(MyContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useData must be used within a <Parent />");
  }

  return context;
};

function Parent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const value = [data, setData];

  // Step 3. Use Context Provider and pass the value of the props that
  // need to be used by any children down the tree
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={value}>
      <Child />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Child() {
  return <ChildTwo />;
}

function ChildTwo() {
  // Step 4. Extract the prop from the Context that you need using custom hook
  const [data, setData] = useData();

  useEffect(() => {
    setData("new data"); //Calling setter here to update
  }, [setData]);

  return (...);
}
```

Comment: You can to that, but you should not pass setter functions around especially to generic reusable components like Dropdown, RadioButtons etc. Your TypeScript in the child compeonent also gets unnecessary more complicated when you pass setters around instead of the child component just knowing that a callback gets called (`() => void`). A Child component should not have to know anything about the state that you manage in the parent, because that makes reading your code unnecessary complicated. Why would you care about the state of the parent when reading the child components code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is perfectly ok. You can also utilize useContext() (global variables/functions) and even consider using an HOC in the future if you'll be working with many hooks. Then you can centralize all of the hooks to one component and re-use them throughout your application.

For an HOC some common use cases from my past projects are:

- Errors
- Validation
- Authentication